# Jquery How to get information from a complex JSON string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Please I have this form :

```
<form>

    <p>
      <label for="field_userAddress">Adresse (*)</label>
      <input type="text" name="userAddress" id="field_userAddress"  />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="field_userCP">CP (*)</label>
      <input type="text" name="userCP" id="field_userCP"  />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="field_vars[1]">vars one (*)</label>
      <input type="text" name="vars[1]" id="field_uservars[1]"  />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="field_vars[2]">Vars two (*)</label>
      <input type="text" name="vars[2]" id="field_vars[2]"  />
    </p>


</form>
```

And I desire to control fields using AJAX, So I did the work on the php side and finally I request using JQuery a json string in this way :

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "err": {
        "userAddress": "required",
        "userCP": "required"
    },
    "errr": {
        "vars": {
            "1": "required",
            "2": "required"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display every message in front of the field in question.

So for the first "err", I used those lines and it works :

```
$.each(r.err,function(k,v)
                        {
                            form.find('[name='+k+']').closest('p').append(v);
                        });
```

but for the second one "errr", I tried those lines :

```
$.each(r.errr.vars,function(y,z)
                        {
                            form.find('[name="'+y+'['+z+']"'+']').closest('p').append(z);
                        });
```

It doesn't work !

I found this a little bit complex for me. Please any advise ?

Comment: So the names of the fields would be `1[required]`, `2[required]` etc?

Comment: show some html that this would match up to

Comment: No it would be vars[1] and vars[2] and the message to display is "required"

Comment: Then your selector would be `find('[name="vars['+y+']"'+']')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing part of the point of json. If you want a variety of required fields, you should instead just have one json array called required.

```
{
   "err": {
     "required": ["userAddress", "userCP"]
   },

   "errr": {
     "vars": {
       "required": ["1", "2"];
     },
   }
}
```

And if you want to parse this

$.each( r.err, function(k,v)
  {
    $('form[name='+ v +']').closest('p').append(k);
  });

Comment: Thanks, but its just because I use varity of messages : "required" "invalid email", "invalid zip" ect...

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `[]` that are part of the name per jQuery selector escaping rules.

This should work:

```
$.each(r.errr.vars,function(y,z) {
        form.find('input[name="vars\\['+y+'\\]"]').closest('p').append(z);
});
```

API docs http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Read top paragraph regarding escaping

Comment: You don't need to escape it because its quoted, though your code is missing the closing `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use ID's to target specific input fields and hand over the error message. Instead of using [] in the id attribute i suggest doing something like this:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <p>
      <label for="field_userAddress">Adresse (*)</label>
      <input type="text" name="userAddress" id="field_userAddress"  />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="field_userCP">CP (*)</label>
      <input type="text" name="userCP" id="field_userCP"  />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="field_vars_1">vars one (*)</label>
      <input type="text" name="vars[1]" id="field_vars_1"  />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="field_vars_2">Vars two (*)</label>
      <input type="text" name="vars[2]" id="field_vars_2"  />
    </p>
</form>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$.each(r.errr.vars,function(y,z) {
    form.find('input#field_vars_'+y).parent().append('<span>'+z+'</span>');
});
```

Works just fine. // http://jsfiddle.net/bbSw9/